# Hardware resource Open/Close methods

Tags: c#, polymorphism

So I'm making a program that is a serial port wedge. In other words I want it to listen to a serial port. If data comes in, wait a given amount of time, then play a sound and finally send the data out.

All of those things have a abstract class associated with it. I'm thinking that I might eventually want to monitor `USB:HID` things so I made a IInput class which has abstract methods of `Open`, `Close`, `ToXmlString`, `ParseXmlString` and has a event of `DataAvailable`. I extend that class with `ComPortInput`.

This is the question of it: Do I subscribe to my data event in the Open method, then unsubscribe in close? Or should I just have it in the initializer. I have a GUI that a user can change any of the 4 elements on this wedge at any time. But I'm not sure what would be the cleanest way of doing this. I'm thinking that the GUI would always create a new instance of my `ComPortInput` class. Part of me wants to force that GUI to have another method like Check Input. which in this case if the COM port was invalid or busy it would return false. Then instead of making a `ComPortInput` I would then want a NoInputInput class (for when I don't want to port forward) If I did it this way then I could get rid of my null checks on the serial port (Much desired) but is that too tricky? (as in too hard to read?) I'm thinking that if i do that I could put in my constructor of `ComPortInput` to Assert not null of the `SerialPort`. To me this looks better

```
public ComPortInput(SerialPort sp, int delay) : base(delay)
{
    if (sp == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Serial port can not be null");

    LibraryTrace.Start("ComPortInput", delay);

    serialPort = sp;
    serialPort.DataReceived += sp_DataReceived;

    LibraryTrace.End("ComportInput");
}
~ComPortInput()
{
    serialPort.Dispose();
}
```

My thoughts on this way, though, is that it might be hard to have a abstract `CheckValidity`... Hmm just thought as I was typing what if I put a `params object[] args` for CheckValidity and just have the comport i could try a few things and return true or false. Then if I ever decide to accept other types of input I could do something similar (such as if it was `USB:HID` I could accept the `PID/VID`) What do you guys think? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Have your class implement `IDisposable` and follow the disposable pattern for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/898867/3312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jesse C. Slicer mentioned, because your class *seems* to encapsulate an `IDisposable` object (assuming `serialPort` would be a private field - this would be clearer if you named it `_serialPort`), it's *asking* to implement the `IDisposable` interface.

Thus, instead of a *destructor*, you would simply have a `Dispose` method:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    serialPort.Dispose();
}
```

Another thing is this `LibraryTrace` whose `Start` and `End` static methods are a testability hinderance. If it's at all possible, I would wrap that with an interface like `ILibraryTrace` and implement it in a `LibraryTraceWrapper : ILibraryTrace` class that exposes the static `LibraryTrace` methods as instance methods - and inject it into the constructor as a dependency - same goes for the `SerialPort`:

```
private readonly ILibraryTrace _trace;
private readonly ISerialPort _serialPort;

public ComPortInput(ILibraryTrace tracer, ISerialPort sp, int delay) : base(delay)
{
    // ...
}
```

This way you could unit test your class and inject mocks as needed.

As for your non-null assertion, that's called a *guard clause* and it's good because you're *failing fast*; by throwing in the constructor you thwart the instantiation of your class without a *serial port*.

I don't know if it's a typo or if it could be an actual issue, but `LibraryTrace.Start` and `LibraryTrace.End` are not working off the same string parameter value (you have `"ComPortInput"` and `"ComportInput"` - those are *not* the same string in C#). Given you're passing in the type's name, I would seriously consider passing in `typeof(this).Name` instead of a magic string. This shields both calls from an eventual *rename* refactoring.

Comment: Yeah I hated updating those strings so I moved to reflection for those. End result is much better as I only have Start() ad End() now and Reflection puts in the name of the function for me. I know its a performance hit, but I use this method on another library that requires speed and it's not been hindering it enough to delete all logging. Thank your input.

Comment: Have you tried `typeof()`? I'm guessing you're using `GetType()` - if the type is in the same assembly, `typeof()` performs better (per MSDN - just closed the tab...sorry)

Comment: @RobertSnyder feel free to mark your [rather old] question as answered, as you [probably] know [we're on a mission](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/999/23788) :)

Comment: HA.. i didn't know that. I had to look up my code and apparently I had C++ on the mind. `public static string __FUNCTION__ {get{return new StackFrame(3).GetMethod().Name; }` hahahah. I did not know about typeof(this).Name I'll have to give that a shot if performance becomes an issue
        }

Comment: You're unwinding the stack? That's another quite significant performance hit!